# Algorithm to find average position

Tags: algorithm

[image]

In the given diagram, I have the extreme left and right points, that is -2 and 4 in this case. So, obviously, I can calculate the width which is 6 in this case.

**What we know:**

The number of partitions:3 in this case
The partition number at at any point i.e which one is 1st,second or third partition
(numbered starting from left)

**What I want:**

The position of the purple line drawn which is positio of average of a particular 
partition

So, basically I just want a generalized formula to calculate position of the average at any point.

Comment: are purple lines odd numbers and red lines even? what's your definition of the purple lines ? why are they different from red ones ?

Comment: How can you have three averages? Averages are obtained by summing the values and dividing by the number of values. Is that not working for this situation?

Comment: What about (width / partition count) * (partitionNo + 0.5)?

Comment: @TomTsagk: purple lines are the averages of red lines at either ends

Comment: @Byte56: average of the two red lines at either ends is the purple line which I consider the average.

Comment: @wondra: This will not be able to handle and give averages that are at negativeaxis

Comment: @Simran kaur Just translate it. left + (width / partition count) * (partitionNo + 0.5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:
`(width/amountPartitions) * partitionNo + (width/amountPartitions/2) + posFirstPartition`

So for your example for the first partition (counting from 0) this would be:
`(6/3) * 0 + (6/3/2) - 2`
`1 - 2`
`-1`
Which should be what you indicated in your picture.
*This is assuming all partitions are the same size.*